# LayerDrawable addLayer in < API level 23

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list, layerdrawable

Is there a way add a layer to a `LayerDrawable` on API < 23? Do I have to create a new `LayerDrawable` using the constructor just adding the new layer?